# Creating a struct that contains list types in go

Tags: list, go, struct

I have created a struct, this struct has contains two list types within it. When I try to instantiate my struct I receive the error

`cannot use list.New() (type *list.List) as type list.List in field value`

I am using the golang playground

**The struct**

```
type myStruct struct {
    name string
    messages list.List
    users list.List
    lastUsed time.Time
}
```

**Instantiating the struct**

```
var myVar = myStruct{"hello", list.New(), list.New(), time.Now()}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: You're trying to assign a pointer to a concrete value.

Comment: @Flimzy The error message doesn't mention a pointer or a concrete value, so it wasn't clear to me. I understand now that the * means pointer, but it's been a few years since I've worked with pointers.

Comment: Well, it does mention those.  `*list.List` means pointer, `list.List` means concrete value.  If these concepts are new to you, you should start with [A Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1).

Comment: @Flimzy They are not new, I am just rusty using them, I've already done that tour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

list.New() returns a pointer `*List`, while myStruct announce its fields as `List`.

> func New() *List

messages and users should be *list.List

```
type myStruct struct {
    name string
    messages *list.List
    users *list.List
    lastUsed time.Time
}
```

Another approach according to your need, u can just initialize the struct as below:

```
var myVar = myStruct{"hello", *list.New(), *list.New(), time.Now()}
```

Comment: Thanks, will using pointers to lists cause any problems? My original intention was to just use a list and not use a pointer. Is there a way to pass a new list to the struct instead of passing a pointer?

Comment: So now your dereferencing the list.New() when you create it, so that you pass the actual list into the struct, is that correct?

Comment: You have to remove the '*' from the struct if you add it in the function call.

I'm not sure which one I should be using. The struct is going to be a chatroom, that holds a list of messages and a list of users. I'm adding these chatrooms to a global list in my program. Would I want the struct to have pointers to lists, or concrete lists.

Comment: @Jacob see [pointers vs values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452323/go-performance-whats-the-difference-between-pointer-and-value-in-struct)

Answer (score 2):

You are creating wrong struct because go, according to `list` package `New()` method returns pointer type of list and you created `list` in struct without pointer.

```
func New() *List
```

So, according to doc you need to created your struct like below:

```
type myStruct struct {
    name string
    messages *list.List
    users *list.List
    lastUsed time.Time
}
```

[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FcD-u32mnUn)

Comment: Thanks, will using pointers to lists cause any problems? My original intention was to just use a list and not use a pointer. Is there a way to pass a new list to the struct instead of passing a pointer?